# How to read RGB image (JPG) without additional module in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read image.jpg (RGB) into an array in python without any additional module but it doesn't work?

```
pic = open('image.jpg')
array=[]
with open(p, 'rb') as inf:
    jpgdata = inf.read()
values=jpgdata.split()
array=array.append(values[:][:])
print (array)
```

Can anyone help me how to read an image 3 bands (RGB) in python without using external module?

Answer (score 3):

A [JPEG image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) is not just a series of pixels, unlike some other formats like BMP.

In order to get the pixel data from a JPEG image you need to decompress it, which involves reading its header data, then rebuilding the data from 8x8px blocks which contain information regarding the brightness and color (YCbCr).

You need to:

- Build the Huffman tree and revert the blocks
- Invert the discrete cosine transform with the given parameters
- Revert the YCbCr into RGB
- Place each block into its corresponding location in the image

Building a simple decoder from scratch is certainly possible, but it's not going to be done in a few lines.